# Probability of the first time that a chain on $\mathbb{Z}$ hits a state.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider the following Markov chain on $\mathbb{Z}$ with transition probabilities given by $p(i,j)=1/2$ if $j=-1$, $p(i,j)=1/2$ if $j=i+1$ and $0$ otherwise. I want to find the probability $\mathbb{P}_{0}(T_{-1}=n)$ for each $n\geq 1$, where $T_{-1}$ is the first time the chain hits $\{-1\}$.

I found that $\mathbb{P}_{0}(T_{-1}=1)=1/2$. However, I have troubles to find $\mathbb{P}_{0}(T_{-1}=n)$ for $n\geq 2$. By the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation, it is reasonable that $\mathbb{P}_{0}(T_{-1}=2)=p^{2}(0,-1)=0$. What about for general $n$?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: your use of $j=-1$ is non-standard and awkward.  The standard choices are at $j = 0$ or $j = 1$ giving a chain  $P :=\left(\begin{matrix}
1-p_1 & p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_2 & 0 & p_2& 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_3 & 0 & 0 & p_3 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_4 & 0 & \dots\\
1-p_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & p_5 & \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{matrix}\right)$.  This is known as an **Age** chain for renewal processes.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for the event $\{T_{-1}=n\}$ to occur is if the the first $n-1$ steps of the process are $i\to (i+1)$, and then the $n^{th}$ step is $(n-1)\to 0$. The probability of this occurring is $(1/2)^n$.

By the way, you erred in applying the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation. The correct way is
$$
P_0(T_{-1}=2)=\sum_j p(0,j)p(j,-1)
$$
Since the only $f$ for which $p(0,j)$ is nonzero is $j=1$, $P_0(T_{-1}=2)=p(0,1)p(1,-1)=1/4$. In general, you need to sum over all possible paths the Markov process can take, but since your process is so simple, there always only a single path from $0$ to $-1$ which has length $n$ and does not hit $-1$ prematurely.

Comment: I can't follow the notation $\{T_{n}=-1\}$. $T_{n}$ is the first positive integer the chain reaches $-1$?

Comment: @Tsk Brain fart, fixed.